# Mercurial linear history using hg rebase with uncommited changes

Tags: version-control, mercurial, dvcs, tortoisehg

Suppose I have several commits in local repo, and some uncommited changes in working dir.
After `hg pull`, `hg update`, I get a couple of new changesets from central repo which create a new head in local repo.

Now suppose, I don't want to merge those two heads and push, in which case I'll get the message that I have uncommited changes in working dir, when trying to merge.

As well, suppose I don't want to use `hg shelve` in order to shelve uncommited changes and merge without problems, but would like to create a linear history by using `hg rebase`, so I put my commits on top of pulled commits. When I do rebase, effectively I do a merge, as presented [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Mercurial//Desired_Features), under `hg rebase` chapter.

Now my question is, will I get the same error message: "can't do merge, there are uncommited changes", since `hg rebase` does implicit merge, or not?

If yes, then I will have to use `hg shelve` in both cases: explicit merge of two heads and implicit merge when rebasing, no?

Thanks in advance,
Cheers

Comment: Do you have to fix the history before you commit? Why not wait until you commit later and then fix the history then? And the best way to find out, simply make a complete copy of the entire working folder using normal OS operations (like Copy/Paste in Windows for instance), and experiment in one of the copies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Suppose I have several commits in local repo, and some uncommited changes in working dir. After hg pull, hg update, I get a couple of new changesets from central repo which create a new head in local repo.

If you have uncommitted changes in the working dir, and `hg pull` gives you a new head from upstream, `hg update` will tell you:

```
abort: crosses branches (merge branches or use --clean to discard changes)
```

If you try to merge, you will then get a message about not being able to merge with uncommitted changes.

All this is for very good reason: if changes aren't committed, they are subject to being lost forever when the merge machinery kicks in. You should either commit or shelve your uncommitted changes before trying to merge with or rebase onto the upstream code.

You might also look into using MQ to help you with this; MQ and rebase are designed to play well together, so if your local not-quite-finished changes are managed by MQ, all you have to do is `hg qrefresh; hg pull --rebase`.

Answer (score 5):

The simple answer is yes. `hg rebase` will not allow you to perform a rebase when you have uncommitted edits. There are a few solutions, none of which is perfect:

- Commit your oustanding work, do the rebase, then `hg export tip > foo.patch`, `hg strip tip`, and `hg import --no-commit foo.patch`.
- Use `hg shelve`. I can't comment on this in detail since I haven't tried it.
- Create a new named branch with `hg branch <branch-name>` and commit your outstanding work on the named branch. You can then use `hg rebase --keepbranches --base <branch-name> --dest default` to rebase your working branch on top of new changes. Personally I find working with named branches (which never escape my clone to upstream) to be a very nice way to manage this sort of workflow, since it makes it easy to move back and forth between upstream and my current project[s], and there is no penalty for committing on a branch.

Comment: There's [an easier way](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/TipsAndTricks#Merge_or_rebase_with_uncommitted_changes) to do the same as the first of your bullet points.